# How can I loop this (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, object, loops

```
{

    "fulltime": [

        {"name": "oscar godson", "age": "20", "email": "oscargodson@hismail.com"},

        {"name": "daniel erickson", "age": "25", "email": "daniel@wraithtech.com"},

        {"name": "john doe", "age": "18", "email": "john.doe@mycompany.com"}

    ],

    "parttime":[

        {"name": "bill johnson", "age": "35", "email": "billjohnson@gmail.com"}

    ]



}
```

and not knowing any of these values, e.g. fulltime could equal any thing. im looking for a function/method to loop through it all... Please, no jQuery.

Also, i want to basically get the output of: fulltime -> all inside of fulltime, parttime -> all inside of parttime, etc

Comment: what's the use of your looping? validation? visualization?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in your_object) {
    console.log(key + " people:");
    // "key" is "fulltime", "parttime", etc
    for (var i = 0; i < your_object[key].length; i++) {
        console.log(your_object[key][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But, i want a more verbose output... e.g. fulltime then all the stuff inside of fulltime, then parttime, then all of whats in parttime, etc.

Comment: im getting fulltime people: -> fulltime, fulltime, etc, its not showing the people's data?

Comment: @Oscar Godson: I suggest you read more about the different kinds of loop statements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements You now know how to iterate over the properties of an object, adjusting it to your needs should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have Firebug installed:

```
for(var key in json) {
  //"fulltime", "parttime"
  console.log("Checking " + key);
  for(var i = 0; i < json[key].length; i++){
    var person = json[key][i];
    //Each person
    for(var prop in person) {
      console.log(prop + ": " + person[prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Be careful that you don't iterate with `for ... in ...` over an array. To iterate over an array, use the "regular" way with `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a recursive function. But you need to be careful about circular references. See example below:

```
  var arr = [];

  /**
   * Gets the string representation of the specified object. This method is
   * used for debugging
   * @param {Object} Object to convert to string
   * @return {String} The string representation of the object
   */
  var toObjectSource = function(obj)   {
     if(obj === null)   {
        return "[null]";
     }
     if(obj === undefined) {
        return "[undefined]";
     }

     var str = "[";
     var member = null;
     for(var each in obj)   {
        try   {
           member = obj[each];
           if(arr.indexOf(member) === -1) { // the indexOf function is not available
                                            // on older versions of js
              arr.push(member);
              str += each + "=" + toObjectSource(member) + ", "; // but beware of this
                                                                // recursive call!!!
           }
        }catch(err) {
           alert(err);
        }
     }
     return str + "]";
  }
```

The reason for the check is that. It will give you "too much recursion" in case the object is like this:

```
 var obj = {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
 }
 obj.c = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can verify your JSON data in http://www.jsonlint.com/.

If you not yet convert the string with JSON to the object you should use `JSON.parse` function from the web browser or from http://www.json.org/js.html to convert input string to the object.

For looping through the properties of a object you can use `"for in"` loop. It is generally always recommended to use this loop in the following form:

```
for (var name in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

(see for example http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#forin for the explanation). You should don't forget to declare `name` as `var name` either inside of `for` statement or somewhere before. If you forget this the variable will be interpret as a global and your code will run slowly.

Loop through element of an array in more effective with a standard `for` loop instead of `"for in"` loop. Moreover to receive more performance advantages you should always cache an index of a property used more as one time in a local variable. For example the the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < your_object[key].length; i++) {
    console.log(your_object[key][i]);
}
```

should be better rewritten as following:

```
var arr = your_object[key];
var len = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```